# How objects created in java's heap space have global access?

Tags: java, object, global, heap-memory

An online course and other websites repeatedly say that objects created in heap space have global access. Does this global access mean that the object can be access from anywhere in the program before being destroyed by the garbage collector? If this is true, please also add a short code showing this.

Source:

1. Course: [YouTube](https://youtu.be/Kj_Z9Ao0IDw?t=48s)
2. "Any object created in the heap space has global access and can be referenced from anywhere of the application." [JournalDev](https://www.journaldev.com/4098/java-heap-space-vs-stack-memory)

Comment: Could you provide one of your sources? Never heard or seen anything like that...

Comment: @spaceborg Added the source

Comment: It is bogus/wrong, and makes no sense. Objects created in the heap doesn't have any special "access". The phrasing implies that objects created elsewhere .... Well that doesn't make sense, because you can only create objects on the heap. --- *"referenced from anywhere **of** the application"* It's not even good English. I think the entire paragraph is bad English, and maybe the writer meant to say *"Any object created in the heap space **is globally accessible** and can be referenced from anywhere **in** the application"*, which is technically true, but only if you know how to **reach** them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This simply means that objects, which actually reside in **heap** **space**, can be accessed by any thread, from anywhere in the program. That is, if a given thread knows where the object resides in heap space.

Then there is a **stack** **memory**, which for all the practical purposes you could consider a **local** memory for the methods. References to objects in heap and primitive values are stored in stack memory. If thread A creates reference to object OBJ, another thread B cannot access this reference unless thread A shares(copy) it with B.

However,  thread B can also create it's own local reference to the object.

This is overly simplistic answer, however the proper answer is not fit for the Stack Overflow forum format. Luckily, there are plenty resources which cover java memory model in great detail.

Therefore, please read this tutorial, i don't think it can be explained much better than here:
[memory model](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/java-memory-model.html)

Comment: Keep in mind that in order to access to any object within the heap, you must have a reference to it, and that would apply to almost any programming language.

So, when they say "global access" it doesn't mean "you can see objects floating on the heap just because you wanted to", but "there's no restriction that any thread within the same process can access to the exact same instance by sharing its reference", which is why you need synchronization blocks, semaphores, etc. to enforce thread-safety.

Regarding heap dumps, that can happen regardless of the programming language,

Comment: @DanielCuadra i wasn't even going in that direction. There is a link included in the answer which in great detail discuses java memory model, thread safety and so on. There's no restriction that any thread within the same process can access to the exact same instance by sharing its reference. I thought i said the same with: That is, if a given thread knows where the object resides in heap space.Tl;dr the answer is intentionally simplistic because there is a great deal of resources, some included in this answer, which extensively cover the topic.

Comment: Fyi, strictly speaking you don't have to have direct reference to the object. You could instead have a reference to locator service which has reference to objects that you could lookup from the heap.  An example would be when you ask spring container explicitly for a bean by it's name.

Comment: Sorry, @John, my comment was intended for the OP, but some reason I couldn't tag the OP directly. I knew you were sound on your answer.